# Create many columns of predictions from a single function and many parameterisations

Tags: r

I have a function with 100 sets of parameters obtained from separate simulations. I also have a data frame with many values at which I want to make predictions based on the parameter sets.

So, I want to create a column of predicted values based on each parameter set. I want to know the most efficient way to create all 100 columns (can be named preds001-preds100, for example).

Here's a small reproducible example that demonstrates the type of input & function I have, and the type of output I would like.

```
coefs <- data.frame(intercept = c(1, 2, 3),
                    slope = c(5, 4, 3))

predfunc <- function(x, intercept, slope) {
  intercept + x * slope
}

dat <- data.frame(xvals = c(10, 20, 30)) %>%
  mutate(preds1 = predfunc(xvals, coefs$intercept[1], coefs$slope[1]),
         preds2 = predfunc(xvals, coefs$intercept[2], coefs$slope[2]),
         preds3 = predfunc(xvals, coefs$intercept[3], coefs$slope[3]))

dat
```

I've also tried a loop with a `paste0` to change the column name inside `mutate`, but this fails.

```
for (i in 1:100){
  dat <- dat %>%
    mutate(paste0('preds', i) = predfunc(xvals, coefs$intercept[1], coefs$slope[1]))
}
```

Even if it worked, the loop wouldn't be a great solution, of course. I'd appreciate it if you could help me find a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `:=` as assignment operator with `!!` to create columns

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(xvals = c(10, 20, 30)) 
for (i in 1:100){
  dat <- dat %>%
    mutate(!!paste0('preds', i) := 
     predfunc(xvals, coefs$intercept[1], coefs$slope[1]))
}
```

---

or using `map`

```
library(purrr)
map2_dfc(coefs$intercept, coefs$slope,
    ~predfunc(dat$xvals, .x, .y)) %>% 
   setNames(paste0("preds", seq_along(.))) %>%
   bind_cols(dat, .)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sapply` with `cbind()`

```
r = cbind(dat, sapply(dat$xvals, predfunc, coefs$intercept,coefs$slope))
```

You can wrap the above in `setNames` as @akrun demonstrates, or assign directly afterward (i.e. `names(r)[-1]<-paste0("pred",ncol(r)-1)`)

Output:

```
  xvals pred3 pred3 pred3
1    10    51   101   151
2    20    42    82   122
3    30    33    63    93
```